# Using Lingpipe for word-level language model

Tags: java, nlp, classification, document-classification

I have been trying to get a word-level language model to work on lingpipe. All the examples and tutorials I have come across show the character-n-gram model. How to I go about using lingpipe to train a word-level model and then use that model to test it on other documents?

Additionally, I noticed that TokenizedLM is not serializable. Is there no way I can save it and load it later without having to go through re-training every time?

Lastly, are there any other frameworks/tools that will allow me to do this without any coding on my part?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Java, but if you are not bound to that programming language there is the Python [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/), which has [tokenizers](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tokenize-module.html) and [ngram-models](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.model.ngram.NgramModel-class.html) and lots of [other stuff](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk-module.html). There is also a [book](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/book.html) which can be used as introduction and to get an overview.

Comment: I am aware of NLTK, and I am also not bound to Java by any means. This is one of those "because it is there" issues. I found the [MITLM](http://code.google.com/p/mitlm/) package very useful for language models.

Comment: These links are unusable - they refer to a server that requires a login. Please replace them with links to publicly-accessible documentation (assuming that's what you meant to link to) if you want your answer to be helpful.